# Hide text after div using css

Tags: html, css

Here is my Div:

```
<div id="show" class="dataTables_length">
    Show 
    <select size="1" name="show_length">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="20">25</option>
        <option value="30">50</option>
        <option value="40">100</option>
   </select> 
   entries
</div>
```

I want to hide this `show` and `entries` text how should I hide this using css? Not using javascript or jquery.

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in a `<span>`. CSS can't be applied to text nodes.

Comment: `style="visibility: hidden"` didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

```
.someClass {
  display: none; 
}
```

Tried this? I am sure this would do it!

Where it would be this:

```
<span class="someClass">Show</span>
<!-- select statement here -->
<span class="someClass">Enteries</span>
```

I thought you wanted to hide whole of it!

Comment: It will. But it'll also hide the `<select>` element too.

Comment: I would argue highly against using the same text for an ID and a class. This will only confuse you later on. Use `.show-text` or similar instead.

Comment: Using the classname `showClass` is a bit weird for something that's hidden.. right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="show" class="dataTables_length">
    <span class="hidden">Show</span>
    <select size="1" name="show_length">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="20">25</option>
        <option value="30">50</option>
        <option value="40">100</option>
    </select> 
    <span class="hidden">entries</span>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
span.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite so many answers and comments, you don't seem to be ready to accept the fact that the text needs to be wrapped in span. And that too using only css!

So, you can do a `faux` hide like this: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/R7Yt4/1/**

CSS:

```
div#show {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
}

div#show::selection {
    color: #ccc;
}

div#show > select {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: 'faux hide'... I love the term :P

Answer (score 0):

You can warp a span around the items you want to hide, and the hide this. 
For example

```
<span class="hide">Show</span>
```

and css:

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

Your full html will look like this:

```
<div id="show" class="dataTables_length">
    <span class="hide">Show</span>
    <select size="1" name="show_length">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="20">25</option>
        <option value="30">50</option>
        <option value="40">100</option>
    </select> 
    <span class="hide">entries</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="show" class="dataTables_length">
    <span style="visibility:hidden">Show </span>
    <select size="1" name="show_length">
        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
        <option value="20">25</option>
        <option value="30">50</option>
        <option value="40">100</option>
   </select> 
  <span style="visibility:hidden">  entries </span>
</div>
```